# Extract string from a String in c#

Tags: c#, string, hyperlink, extract

How can I get this:

```
Mu6AQUVX/YWxpYmFkOTE5KycrMzJAZ21haWwuY29t/?app_redirect=False"
```

From the link:

```
https://facebook.com/accounts/confirm_email/Mu6AQUVX/YWxpYmFkOTE5KycrMzJAZ21haWwuY29t/?app_redirect=False"
```

Extracting this string:?

```
#039;ll see their posts in your feed.</p></td></tr><tr style=""><td height="30" style="line-height:30px;" colspan="1">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td style=""><a href="https://facebook.com/accounts/confirm_email/Mu6AQUVX/YWxpYmFkOTE5KycrMzJAZ21haWwuY29t/?app_redirect=False" style="color:#3b5998;text-decoration:none;display:block;width:370px;"><table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><tr>
```

Comment: show the code you've tried, the problem you have and the expected output. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to get string between two words:

```
public static String GetTextBetween(String source, String leftWord, String rightWord)
        {
            return
                Regex.Match(source, String.Format(@"{0}\s(?<words>[\w\s]+)\s{1}", leftWord, rightWord),
                            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups["words"].Value;
        }
```

Call below function with your arguments:

`GetTextBetween("your full text to search from", "start fix text", "end fix text")`

Comment: If . And : not working then include punctuation in pattern: replace (?<words>[\w\s]+) to (?<words>[\w\s.:]+)